# Django: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm actually learning to use the Django framework with PostgreSQL with Docker and docker-compose.

Regularly, when I make a mistake (for example a syntax error in the views.py file), I cannot reach my Django app anymore trough my web browser.

Firefox tells me:

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000

Chrome tells me:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I had this several times and I always managed to find the error in my code, to correct it and then everything went well again.

Currently, my code is working fine. But if I encounter this again (and this happens very often), I would like to be able to find the error quickly by myself.

So here is my question:

**How can I see which file at which line contains the error ?**

**I would like to have a correct error message telling me what went wrong instead of that annoying ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED browser page over and over.**

I hope I explained my issue well because I struggled to describe it to Google.

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

FYI:

```
Ubuntu               18.04.3 LTS Bionic (window manager i3wm)
Docker               19.03.4
docker-compose       1.17.1
python               3.7 (docker image)
Django               2.2.6 (inside the python 3.7 image)
PostgreSQL           12.0 (docker image)
Visual Studio Code   1.39.2
```

Comment: "if I encounter this again (and this happens very often)" -- what trends do you see there?  When you detect it, how do you discover it?  Most importantly: how are you starting django?  Don't you get an error there?

Bottom line is that you can't debug a remote problem that was fatal for django remotely via http: you have to use `ssh` or some other mechanism to find out what went wrong.  But during development most people encounter this sort of fatal error at the terminal that they started django from, so it's clear what failed there.

Comment: Also your django is running in a container so make sure to allow your host machine IP in the Allowed Host in settings.py

Comment: `docker logs CONATNER`is a good place to start and enabling Debug mode in Django

Comment: If you’re actively developing your application, you will probably find it far easier to _first_ make the application work and _second_ package it in Docker.  Make sure `pytest` and `./manage.py` work locally, in a virtual environment, before you start trying to run it in Docker.  This will get you better diagnostics and a shorter feedback loop.

Comment: @BrianCain This happened almost 10 times today. If i don't see the problem directly, I undo my changes one by one until my app works again to see which modification causes the problem. (I test my code regularly and I commit my code a lot by habits, so most of the time I don't have to undo a lot) I start Django via my docker-compose and a python Dockerfile where I ad Django in the requirements.txt. I never leave my app in an unstable state (where I cannot run it normally) so I never have any errors when I start it.

Comment: @Vincent I have access to my app when there is no errors in my code, so I think this is not the issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze I already did some test apps without Docker but I took the habit to do everything with Docker now. So I can work on it on almost every computer regardless of the OS (which is such a pain in the a** without Docker). By the way, all the apps at my jobs are in containers so I must do this too. But your idea is quite good for other developers. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I had the bad habit to run my docker-compose in detached mode.

When attached, the syntax errors are shown directly from the terminal when de container is stopped.
I also added a script where I run my server in a loop. This way, the server will relaunch automatically over and over until I correct the error. I don't have to restart my Django server manually.

Thank you for helping me anyway.